# Moodle - Teacher should see list of Classwise Students

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, chamilo-lms

We are creating an LMS (for multiple Schools) where when teacher of a particular School logs in, he/she should see Students that belongs to the Teacher School only. Also, Teacher would be assign to Classes, hence only those Classes should be visible to the Teacher (not other classes of the Teacher school which are assigned to other Teachers).

So Teacher should see his/her assigned classes and on click on any Class, list of Student that belongs to that class should be displayed.

Further, when Teacher clicks the Student () from the list, teacher needs to submit an assessment (Result) of that selected Student.
I know, the requirement is bit complex, but I trust the experts here to provide me the best possible way to achieve this. :)

Thanks!

Comment: You should state what you have tried already and why it hasn't worked.

Comment: I am not able to find an appropriate approach for this. . . So far we are think of creating Cohort Sync for each class of each school. but this would end up creating so many Cohort sync . ..